# How to dynamically select drop-down lists in angular 5?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to implement a select option for angular 5 with dynamic selection box depends on which backend component sends the selection.

[image]

Please note that both of the selectBox are the same box just the value inside of the option changes.

***selector.html***

```
<html>
...
    <select>
            <option *ngFor="let selectorA in selectorAs">{{selectorAs}}</option>
    </select>
...
```

***selector.ts***

```
import{component} from '@angular/core'
@component({
selector: 'app-root'
templateUrl: './selector.html'
styleUrl: './selector.css'
})
export class AppComponent{
title = 'app';
selectorAs = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
selectorBs = ["option A", "option B", "option C"];
```

So my question is how do i make the select option dynamic to choose selectorBs instead of selectorAs based on the flag it passes in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a variable that points to the current list of choices:

```
export class AppComponent{
  choicesA = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"];
  choicesB = ["option A", "option B", "option C"];
  currentChoiceList: string[];

  processBackendData() {
    this.currentChoiceList = condition ? this.choicesA : this.choicesB;
  }
}
```

and use it in the template:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let choice of currentChoiceList">{{choice}}</option>
</select>
```